# In Django, why does my form context variable disappear?

Tags: django, django-forms

Take this example form.

```
class TestForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields["test"] = forms.CharField()
```

In my view, I have this code:

```
test_form = TestForm()
context['test_form'] = test_form
```

If I `print(test_form)`, it will appear just fine. Now, when I use `{% debug %}` in my template, this is the output: `{ ... 'test_form': , ... }`. In other words, the form disappears. I suspect it has something to do with adding a field after initialization, but I would really like to know **why?** Also how to get around the seeming limitation, if possible.

Comment: If you don't show us the view, then all we can do is guess what the problem might be. Why do you think that the `__init__` method is the problem? Does the form display if you remove it?

Comment: could you add more code of your view? how are you sending the context to the template?

Answer (score 0):

To test if your form has disappeared, you can try displaying it:

```
{% for field in test_form %}
    {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

This should display the each field of the form as HTML. Hope it helps!

Comment: That doesn't work because test_form doesn't even exist in the context, like I said in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your contact variable hasn't disappeared: it's right there, in the output you show us. If it had disappeared, you wouldn't see the `test_form` key in that dictionary.

As to why you don't see a value for that key, that's simply because the default representation of a python object is like this `<TestForm object at ....>`, and your browser is interpreting the angle brackets as an unknown HTML tag which it ignores.

Put your debug tag within `<pre>...</pre>` tags and you'll see it just fine.

Comment: I doubt that's it because I have another form which displays just fine, and appears like this in the debug: `'form_info': .ProfileEditForm object at 0x0000000003DCA160>`.

Comment: Update: Just tried what you suggested and it's still not there. Appears exactly as I put above. I'm sure the debug tag is auto-escaped.